# "Sane" quantisation of moderate-dimensional analogue data

Tags: probability-distributions, soft-question, data-analysis, packing-problem

Warm-up problem (with solution): Suppose I have a measuring device that spits out a stream of real numbers, which I will model as i.i.d. random variables with range $\mathbb{R}$ and continuous probability distribution $P$. I wish to record a large number of measurements in a digital form, and I am prepared to tolerate some loss of precision to make the recording compact. Let us suppose that the appropriate definition of the amount of loss is the mean squared difference between the measurements and the recording.

I need to solve two sub-problems:

- First, choose a suitable encoding function $e:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$ and a decoding function $d:\text{range}(e)\mapsto\mathbb{R}$.
- Second, choose a lossless compression algorithm that efficiently represents the stream of elements of $\mathbb{N}$ using a stream of binary digits.

I would like to focus on the first sub-problem only: the quantisation scheme. Let us just assume that the second sub-problem has an easy near-optimal solution.

It is common engineering practice to choose $d(n) = nq$ for some "quantum" $q$ which is an adjustable parameter that controls the quality of the recording. For example, JPEG uses this scheme. Let us call such a scheme "uniform", since it is appropriate if $P$ is uniform (on some interval much larger than $q$). However, for typical, highly non-uniform $P$ (as in JPEG!), this scheme fails at least one of the following sanity conditions:$\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatorname{argmin}}$

$$d(n) = \mathbb{E}_P(x | e(x)=n)$$
$$e(x) = \argmin_n |d(n)-x|$$

Here I have used the assumption that loss is measured in a mean squared sense. The first condition minimises the loss with respect to $d$ for fixed $e$, and the second minimises the loss with respect to $e$ for fixed $d$. If one of these is not satisfied, then the quantisation scheme can be improved, i.e. the loss can be reduced and/or the compression improved.

Definition: Let us say that the quantisation scheme $(e, d)$ is "sane" if it satisfies the above two conditions.

Given $P$, it is possible to compute a sane quantisation scheme by using the sanity conditions as an iterative algorithm. This is similar to the well-known K-means clustering algorithm.

Update 2013-11-18: A commenter has identified this as Lloyd's Algorthm.

Side-problem: If we suppose that $e$ is an increasing function onto $[0, N)$, then I think $N$ often uniquely determines the scheme, i.e. the starting point of the iteration doesn't matter. This is true for the uniform distribution, for example. Also, I don't think $e$ can ever have an infinite range. If both properties hold, then the sane schemes form a one-parameter family, in which the parameter $N$ controls the amount of loss. I would be interested to discover necessary or sufficient conditions for these properties to hold.

Actual problem: Now consider the analogous problem but for a measuring device that spits out elements of, say, $\mathbb{R}^{16}$.

It is common engineering practice (e.g. JPEG) to quantise each of the components separately. However, a better analogue to the "uniform" quantisation scheme is to view it as a sphere packing problem. Define $e(\vec x)$ to be the nearest point to $\vec x$ in some sphere-packing lattice, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Wall_lattice . However, the uniform scheme is again sub-optimal for typical real-world $P$.

We can define a "sane" quantisation scheme in exactly the same way as for the 1-dimensional case. In principle, the iterative approach to computing a sane lattice will still work. However, in practice there are just too many points. And if there aren't, I can just increase the $16$ until there are.

So instead of considering arbitrary $d$, we must look for $d$ with some sort of structure that allows it to be represented more compactly, e.g. as a distortion of a well-known lattice or something. But it feels a bit like a sphere-packing problem in a curved space, so it is not clear that distorting the uniform quantisation scheme is the right thing to do.

What would you suggest?

For an easier sub-problem, suppose $P$ is radially symmetric. This is not typical of real-world data, but it would be helpful to see a good solution to this case, as I think it includes an interesting part of the problem.

Comment: It seems to me that this question would fit much better on either [Cross-Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) (our sister site on data analysis and statistics) or [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/). If you agree please flag for moderator attention and we will be happy to move it for you.

Comment: Lattice quantization is a well studied problem of applied algebra. Several constructions use number-theoretic methods, so in that sense this is on-topic here. Non-lattice quantization is more challenging. I'm largely ignorant about that, and not ruling out the possibility that a site with experts on clustering algorithms is a better match. An ad hoc way of using spherical symmetry would be to use some kind of scaling function on the layers of a lattice quantizer to get smaller Voronoi regions in the densely populated areas.

Comment: Will something like [Lloyd's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm) lead to unsatisfactory results? I am mostly just tossing random thoughts on the table. I really am mostly useless in source coding /quantization stuff, but have a little bit of exposure.

Comment: Although the motivation is from signal processing, I think the problem is geometric in nature, so I think I'd like to keep it here.

Comment: A radial distortion of the lattice (which is how I understand scaling the layers of the lattice - correct?) is an attractive idea. It ensures that the origin maintains the "right" number of nearest neighbours. It does, however, mean that other Voronoi cells will become long and thin, which may be suboptimal. It's rather difficult to visualise!

Comment: Thank you for the identification of Lloyd's algorithm. I have added that information to the question. It also opens up sources for me to research the side-problem.